# Msbox en caso de ser exitoso

Tags: c#

Lo que tengo es que capturo los valores ingresados en los textbox y utilizo serialize para convertirlos en xml, quier valir de que si todo salio bien lanzar un msgbox de lo contrario otro msg box con otro contenido pero no se que funcion validar o como poner la condicion, anido mi fragmento del codigo del boton.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Empleado NombreEmpleado = new Empleado();
           // NombreEmpleado.nombre = textBox1.Text;
           // FALTA ESTE  NombreEmpleado.fecha = dateTimePicker1.Text;
           // NombreEmpleado.Genero.genero = comboBox2.Text;
           // NombreEmpleado.Puesto.Puesto = comboBox1.Text;
           // NombreEmpleado.Puesto.Descripcion_Puesto = "atender";
            SerializeToXml<Empleado>(NombreEmpleado, @"C:\Users\Curso\Desktop\xmls\serialize.xml");

        }
        public  void SerializeToXml<T>(T obj, string fileName)

        {

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            //Create a FileStream object connected to the target file 

            System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);

            ser.Serialize(fileStream, obj);

            fileStream.Close();

        }
```

Comment: No se entiende mucho la pregunta. cual es el problema que tenes? a que te referis con validar?

Comment: Validar de que fue exitoso la serializacion y si lo fue mandar un msg box que fue exitoso y si no fue exitoso mandar un msgbox que no fue exitoso

Comment: si falla la serializacion va a tirar un error. Eso deberia estar dentro de un try catch.

Comment: Tendras un ejemplo de como seria por favor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta utilizar un try catch{} como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Empleado NombreEmpleado = new Empleado();
           // NombreEmpleado.nombre = textBox1.Text;
           // FALTA ESTE  NombreEmpleado.fecha = dateTimePicker1.Text;
           // NombreEmpleado.Genero.genero = comboBox2.Text;
           // NombreEmpleado.Puesto.Puesto = comboBox1.Text;
           // NombreEmpleado.Puesto.Descripcion_Puesto = "atender";
            SerializeToXml<Empleado>(NombreEmpleado, @"C:\Users\Curso\Desktop\xmls\serialize.xml");

        }
        public  void SerializeToXml<T>(T obj, string fileName)

        {

        try 
        {           
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            //Create a FileStream object connected to the target file 

            System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);

            ser.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Funciono");
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No funciono.");
            //throw;
        }

        }
```

Comment: no se por que fileName y obj me sale error dice doest not exist in the current context

Comment: Vuelve a intentarlo con la edición que hice

Comment: si funciono, solo le quite el public de void serialize...